# JDBC batch insert or insertion via shell script - which is efficient?

Tags: java, linux, oracle, jdbc

My application runs on linux. It's job is to parse lots of files and store the data to DB. Files to be processed are in GB's and has lots of data to be inserted.

I have 2 ways to achieve it.

1. Do batch Insert - (Spring-JDBC)
2. Write the queries to a file and then call shell script to execute that file which then inserts them to DB.

Which approach is more efficient w.r.t time?

Comment: You would have to do a performance test to be sure but probably not much difference. Why not use something like SQL\*Loader? It *will* be faster than either of the above choices.

Comment: @BrentC Actually JDBC will beat a file of queries, but the database specific "load from file" will be faster than JDBC batch, since it's built for that exact purpose.